# Is there a way to select the actual first child in a shadow dom?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to use the `:first-child()` selector inside a Shadow DOM generated from an Angular component. Unfortunately that doesn't work, because the first child in the shadow-root is always a `style` tag.

I've tried `:first-child` and `:first-of-type`. Both won't work, because while all my items share the `.card` class, they use different HTML elements for semantics: `header`, `main` and `footer`.

Source html for the Angular component:

```
<header class="card header">
   <h1>this is header</h1>
</header>

<main class="card main">
   <h1>this is main</h1>
</main>
```

Excerpt from styles

```
.card {
    padding: ($card-padding / 2) $card-padding;

    &:first-child {
        padding-top: $card-padding;
    }

    &:last-of-type {
        padding-bottom: $card-padding;
    }
}
```

Generated shadow root

```
<ng-component>
#shadow-root
  <style>...</style>
  <header class="card header">...</header>
  <main class="card main">...</main>
</ng-component>
```

I'd like to have the top padding to be twice the regular padding for the first `.card` and the bottom padding to be twice the regular padding for the last `.card`.

I know that I can just wrap my whole content in a `<div>`, but this seems like a workaround to me. Why can't I treat the shadow root as my wrapping container?

Comment: `<style>` tags are placed in the `<head>` of the HTML document. The reason you can't select children is because of the view encapsulation.

Comment: Angular places the style there, because it is the style of the component and the shadow DOM. I can select the children, but my `<header class="card header"` is selected via `:nth-child(2)`, because the `<style>` is a child too.